# How do I use MSBuild with SVN?

Tags: svn, msbuild

How does MSBuild called SVN task?

Are there any examples or tutorials?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

[MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) has tasks to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I often simply do calls to svn in [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) tasks. It has worked fine so far, but perhaps there might be reasons not to.

Example (used to revert AssemblyInfo files that are edited during automatic build):

```
    <Exec Command="svn revert %(AssemblyVersionFile.RelativeDir)%(AssemblyVersionFile.Filename)%(AssemblyVersionFile.Extension)" />
```

Comment: This will show the command on the promot. Eg:- to do an svn update it will show [EXEC]svn update --username --password. Not good

Answer (score 0):

Going a step further, we use MSBUILD with cruisecontrol.net which has a SVN task. We have implemented continuous integration [automatic daily builds every night] using CC.net and get email notifications of the results after the build has been done. here is the [cc.net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) site

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild Extension Pack now knows it too